# What is the difference between clearForm and resetForm in jQuery form plugin?

Tags: jquery

In the jQuery [form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/), there are two options which look almost similar viz. `clearForm` and `resetForm`.

In their manuals, they have written

```
//clearForm: true        // clear all form fields after successful submit 
//resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit
```

I really don't understand the actual difference between these two as they work identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check [the source](http://malsup.github.io/jquery.form.js) of the library you can see that the difference is that `clearForm()` *empties* the values in the fields, whereas `resetForm()` *resets* the value back to its default.

Comment: Oh! right. Why did I not pay attention to it. Thanks.